# Pass Objects or Object Properties to Function?

Tags: matlab

Is there a guideline or recommendation about how to pass object to functions? Is it recommended to always pass the full object to a function:

```
calculateSomething(car1, car2, aircraft)
```

Or is it better to only pass the properties that are really needed to the function?

```
calculateSomething(car1.speed, car1.length, car2.speed, aircraft.height)
```

The first approach seems to be more convenient, especially when the function requires many more properties. However, my intuition tells me that the second approach is more computationally efficient as the function does not has to handle the full objects.

Is there a general programming advice for this or is it for every function a trade-off between readability and speed?

Comment: Always pass the full object, you generally want to keep the number of parameter arguments to a minimum as this decreases complexity and improves readability (and as such is often seen as a code smell) and makes no sense in the light of OOP anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never pass the properties directly. Because that breaks the principles of Object orientated programming, (Encapsulation) specially if it will involve making changes to the properties.

Always use getters and setters to make changes to the object properties.